# VPN configuration errors : route and NLSMG_ERROR: error -101

Tags: vpn, raspbian

I'm trying to use ovpn on my raspeberry (distr. Raspbian) but it doesn't work: Initialization Sequence is Completed, but my IP doesn't change.

Here is the log:

```
Fri Nov  9 13:56:19 2018 WARNING: file 'PrivateKey.key' is group or others accessible
Fri Nov  9 13:56:19 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.0 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 18 2017
Fri Nov  9 13:56:19 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: ******************
Enter Auth Password: ******************
Fri Nov  9 13:56:33 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]194.99.104.5:443
Fri Nov  9 13:56:33 2018 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri Nov  9 13:56:33 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxx
Fri Nov  9 13:56:33 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Nov  9 13:56:34 2018 [5554/server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxx
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 Option 'explicit-exit-notify' in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:3 is ignored by previous <connection> blocks 
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 Note: option tun-ipv6 is ignored because modern operating systems do not need special IPv6 tun handling anymore.
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 GDG6: NLSMG_ERROR: error -101

Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=1
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 172.18.13.122 peer 172.18.13.121
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 /sbin/ip -6 addr add fde4:8dba:82e3::101d/64 dev tun0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Fri Nov  9 13:56:35 2018 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

And, if usefull, here is the .ovpn I used:

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
comp-lzo
nobind
ns-cert-type server
persist-key
persist-tun
reneg-sec 0
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
redirect-gateway
verb 1
auth-user-pass
ca CACertificate.crt
cert UserCertificate.crt
key PrivateKey.key
remote ca.lazerpenguin.com 443
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
keysize 256
```

It's a similar case than [VPN: ERROR: Linux route add command failed with status 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/856768/vpn-error-linux-route-add-command-failed-with-status-2) and someone advised "Try to add the pushed route via ip route add on your guest to check the error and adjust the routing on your host." But I have no idea how to "adjust the routing on my host" ...
Does someone have an idea to solve my problem?

Thanks